# Javascript not working in some browsers

Tags: javascript, popup

I work in training and we host the same materials in two different host locations. In order to use the same materials without having to create a modified copy I used a script to direct to a location based on the host location. As shown here:

```
    function popup(url) 
{
var width  = 1280;
var height = 720;
var left   = (screen.width  - width)/2;
var top    = (screen.height - height)/2;
var params = 'width='+width+', height='+height;
params += ', top='+top+', left='+left;
params += ', directories=no';
params += ', location=no';
params += ', menubar=no';
params += ', resizable=yes';
params += ', scrollbars=yes';
params += ', status=no';
params += ', toolbar=no';

newwin=window.open(url,'windowname4', params);
if (window.focus) {newwin.focus();}

}

if (window.location.hostname=='exacttraining.ekphost.com') {
   popup('https://exacttraining.ekphost.com/exact/servlet/ekp?TX=PAGELAYOUT&MTX=myhome%26');
} else {
   popup('https://exact.ekphost.nl/exact/servlet/ekp?TX=PAGELAYOUT&MTX=myhome%26');
}
```

This has been working very well until suddenly a test reveals that it no longer works in Chrome and Edge but it does still work in IE. Do you know why it would stop working in some browsers (but not all)? Is there anything I can do to make it work every time in all browsers?

Thanks,
Aimee

Comment: Are the popups being blocked by the modern browsers?

Comment: Code works in chrome console for me.

Comment: @Scott It could be but there is no indication on the screen that something is being blocked. You just click and nothing happens. How can I test if it is a pop up blocker ?

Comment: @Shadowfool Does that mean it is something to do with my own (or more likely my companies) settings?

Comment: Most browsers will automatically block popups if they are not initiated directly by a user action (clicking a button).  [Here's an example](https://jsfiddle.net/Kredit/jaw78dqk/).  A message should appear at the right of the address bar in Chrome if a popup is blocked, and you should see an error in the developer console because `newwin` is `null`.

Comment: It is from a button and other javascript popups are working (without the conditional 'If this host... else' part. I just don't get it.